# Have Twurl installed, but I can't access it

Tags: ruby, twurl

I have installed Twurl but for some reason I still can't use it. I believe I have it installed because it shows up when I type the `ls` command. Then I am able to navigate to the folder that Twurl is contained in. However, I am not able to go into the Twurl folder because it says it is not a directory. I am able to use the command `open twurl`, which opens up a seperate terminal window with a lot of information about Twurl, but I can't type anything. One other thing, when I try and run `twurl authorize` I get this response:  `twurl: command not found` So my question is, how do I go about getting twurl to work now? Such that I can run the `twurl authorize` command.

`gem env` output:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.2 (2020-10-01 patchlevel 137) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/CharlieBagin/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/CharlieBagin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/CharlieBagin/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /Users/CharlieBagin/anaconda3/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

I think I might have installed it in two places. I originally used `gem install twurl`, but then it wasn't working and I was trying some things and used bundler to install at some point too.

Comment: Can you show the output of `gem env`?

Comment: How did you install `twurl`?

Comment: I updated the main post with more info

Comment: `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` is where the binary files are installed. Can you run Twurl via `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/twurl`?

Comment: I can not - I am running ```cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin``` and then ```twurl authorize ``` and still getting ```twurl: command not found```. If I try and do ```/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/twurl``` it says ```not a directory```

Comment: When you `cd` into the `bin` directory, you have to run it via `./twurl` i.e. with trailing `./`